# Spring Singleton bean with accessed and modified by more than 1 request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

By default all spring beans are Singleton, So when the container loads, all the bean defined are being created. 
Now if i have a bean say "Person" and it has an attribute "name", When first request comes say r1, it changes person.name="spring", and this request will need this bean say after x seconds, Now during the wait time of r1, say r2 modified the value of person.name =springmvc.

So since bean is singleton, r1 gets the value of name as "springmvc" instead of "spring",

How do we prevent this or my understanding is not right?

Answer (score 0):

So for the `Person` Bean it sounds like you want it scoped `prototype` rather than being a `Singleton` (or `session` if you have a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext).

For that you should annotate you `Person` class like this:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype") 
public class Person { 
     ... Rest of class here...
}
```

Then each request will have it's own instantiation of the `Person` class and you won't need to worry about this conflict.

You can learn more about Springs various scopes [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm).

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `Singleton` depends on the way you configure the `Bean`. If your `Person` is never configured by `Annotation` or `Xml Way`, `Person` is just a normal `Class`, and can be created more times.
In your situation, I think your `Person` object that is created is not a `Thread Safe` variable.
more about [`Thread Safe`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-safety.html)